# Sharing photo to Instagram (scale and crop) view

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, instagram

iIs there any possible way to share photos to Instagram but instead of presenting its Edit view present the Scale & Crop view?

Edit view :

[image]

presenting this view :

[image]

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/instagram-api-developers/0lsJyFcfYPw

Comment: @satheeshwaran Thanks, I change location_id to camera but still shows edit view !